# EF Core - Navigation Collection Property from Computed SQL or Select Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have a transaction class like following:

```
    public class Transaction
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ForeignId { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Transaction> Takes { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to have the navigation property `Takes`, which contains all transactions of the type `Take` that has happened after the current `Transaction` with the same `ForeignId`.

This is an example of the transaction data:

| ID | ForeignID | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | Take | 50 |
| 2 | 42 | Create | 10 |
| 3 | 42 | SomethingUnrelated | 2 |
| 4 | 9 | Take | 3 |
| 5 | 42 | Take | 4 |
| 6 | 42 | Take | 5 |

If we load `ID = 2`:

```
var transaction = dbContext.Transactions.Include(t => t.Takes)
  .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id = 2);
```

I would expect the following data to be in `transaction.Takes`:

| ID | ForeignID | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 42 | Take | 4 |
| 6 | 42 | Take | 5 |

`ID = 1` is not included since it happened before `ID = 2`, `ID = 3` is not included since the type is not `Take` and `ID = 4` is not included since it has another `ForeignID`.

How do I setup this navigation property in the `DbContext.OnModelCreating`?

If i were to find the `Takes` manually it would look like this:

```
var transaction = dbContext.Transactions.Include(t => t.Takes)
  .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == 2);
var takes = dbContext.Transactions.Where(t =>
  t.Id > transaction.Id &&
  t.ForeignId == transaction.ForeignId &&
  t.Type == "Take");
```

**Tried approaches:**

1. I have been looking at `HasComputedColumnSql`, but it does not take any parameters...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().Property(gs => gs.Takes)
  .HasComputedColumnSql("Some SQL...");
```

2. Tried setting up `HasMany` relation with PrincipalKey, but I am not able to exclude data that has happened before (in this case `ID = 1` should be excluded)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasMany(t => t.Takes).WithOne()
  .HasPrincipalKey(t => new {
    Id = t.Id,
    ForeignId = t.ForeignId,
    Type = "Take"
}).HasPrincipalKey(t => new {
    Id = t.Id,
    ForeignId = t.ForeignId,
    t.Type
});
```

Comment: The data may ne be stored in order in the database.  It depends on the database.  For example SQL Server is multi-threaded and each time you do a query you way get results in a different order.  I your case to guarantee you get the numbers with the highest ID you need to sort by ID.

Comment: BTW `Transaction` as a class name or property is not a good idea as it could clash with the database Transaction class/property.

Comment: EF Core supports only FK based relationships and navigations, period. Dead task from the beginning, no need to try, there *isn't* navigation property based solution.